# Entity framework add-migration scaffold with custom Migration base

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I need to scaffold migration with `add-migration` from Package Manager Console with my custom Migration base `CustomMigration` which is derived from `DbMigration`.

```
public partial class NewMigration: CustomMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

I can use different command if needed. I don't have any skills in powershell scripting. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Created new class which generated my migrations:

```
public class AuditMigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
{
    protected override void WriteClassStart(string @namespace, string className, IndentedTextWriter writer, string @base, bool designer = false, IEnumerable<string> namespaces = null)
    {
        @base = @base == "DbMigration" ? "AuditMigration" : @base;
        var changedNamespaces = namespaces?.ToList() ?? new List<string>();
        changedNamespaces.Add("Your.Custom.Namespace");
        base.WriteClassStart(@namespace, className, writer, @base, designer, changedNamespaces);
    }
}
```

In Configuration.cs :

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<EfDataAccess>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        CodeGenerator = new AuditMigrationCodeGenerator();
    }
}
```

And it will use your Custom code generator, which generates migrations with my desired custom migration base.

For more info: https://romiller.com/2012/11/30/code-first-migrations-customizing-scaffolded-code/

Comment: Thank god for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. run command `add-migration NewMigration`. It will add new migration with name "NewMigration". If there is no changes in model, the migration will be empty:

   ```
   public partial class NewMigration : DbMigration
   {
       public override void Up()
       {
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change base class of NewMigration to CustomMigration:

   ```
   public partial class NewMigration : CustomMigration
   {
       public override void Up()
       {
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. modify NewMigration as you wish
4. run `update-database` to apply migration

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is what we do now, which is cumbersome as we do ~10 migrations per day in new projects. We need custom initializations and logic to be done on every migration, e.g. Audit. So this is not acceptable option for us and would like to have scaffold with out custom migration to prevent initialization bugs.